# Method overloading not sure how

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, overloading

i have these methods:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString GetQTip(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string propertyName, string message, string propertyNameOverride = "", QTipPosition position = QTipPosition.Right, bool includeEvents = true, string title = "")
{
  string qtipPosition = String.Empty;

  switch (position)
  {
    case QTipPosition.Right:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'left center', at: 'right center'";
      break;
    case QTipPosition.Left:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'right center', at: 'left center'";
      break;
    case QTipPosition.Top:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'top middle', at: 'bottom middle'";
      break;
    case QTipPosition.Bottom:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'bottom middle', at: 'top middle'";
      break;
  }

  if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyNameOverride))
    propertyName = propertyNameOverride;

  if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
    title = htmlHelper.Resource(Resources.Global.Title.Information);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append(String.Concat("$('#", propertyName, "').removeData('qtip').qtip({content: {text:"));
  sb.Append(String.Concat("'", message, "', title: { text: '", title, "', button: false }}, position: { ", qtipPosition, " }"));

  if (includeEvents)
    sb.Append(", show: { event: 'focus mouseenter', solo: true, ready: false }, hide: 'blur'");

  sb.Append(", style: { classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-yellow' } });");

  return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

how do I call this:

```
 <%: Html.GetQTip("training-module-name-container-" + module.CategoryId +"-" + module.TrainingModuleId, trainingModulePointsHintText, Zinc.Web.Extensions.QTipPosition.Bottom, true, Html.Resource(Resources.Training.Module.Completed.View.TrainingModulePoints))%>
```

I only want these parameters
thanks

Comment: your question is vague. explain what you are trying to achieve and how the example above is wrong...

Comment: oops yes sorry I edited my OP

Comment: What's not working? Which error do you get?

Comment: not to worry thanks, let me try and figure it out :)

Comment: If you want to call a version of GetQTip with less parameters then you need to create a version of the method that calls the original method with a default value for the parameters you are leaving out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't leave out a parameter in the middle.  You can use default parameters, but the ones you leave out have to be the last in the list.  For the MSDN explanation, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

To fix your problem, you have a few options:

1)  Make the `propertyNameOverride` parameter the last parameter in the function definition as follows:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetQTip(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string propertyName, string message, QTipPosition position = QTipPosition.Right, bool includeEvents = true, string title = "", string propertyNameOverride = "") { 
    // do stuff
}
```

You can then leave it out without a problem.

2)  Use the parameter, but just put the default value in:

```
<%: Html.GetQTip("training-module-name-container-" + module.CategoryId +"-" + module.TrainingModuleId, trainingModulePointsHintText, "", Zinc.Web.Extensions.QTipPosition.Bottom, true, Html.Resource(Resources.Training.Module.Completed.View.TrainingModulePoints))%>
```

3)  Write another function with only the parameters you desire, which then calls the full function with default parameters in the "empty" locations:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetQTip(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string propertyName, string message, QTipPosition position = QTipPosition.Right, bool includeEvents = true, string title = "", string propertyNameOverride = "") { 
    return htmlHelper.GetQTip("training-module-name-container-" + module.CategoryId +"-" + module.TrainingModuleId, trainingModulePointsHintText, "", Zinc.Web.Extensions.QTipPosition.Bottom, true, Html.Resource(Resources.Training.Module.Completed.View.TrainingModulePoints))%>
}
```